# Keep ActiveMQ running when losing connection to database

Tags: activemq-classic

I have an instance of ActiveMQ 5.16.4 running that is using MySQL as a persistent data storage. Recently the MySQL server had some issues, and ActiveMQ lost its connection to MySQL. That caused multiple Spring microservices to throw errors because ActiveMQ wasn't working.

Is it possible to have master/slave ActiveMQ running where master and slave uses separate persistence storage?

I have done some research and found ["pure master slave"](https://activemq.apache.org/pure-master-slave), but it says that it is deprecated and not recommend to use and will be removed in 5.8. It says to use shared storage which I am trying to avoid (cause my problem is what if storage itself is down).

What are my options to keep running ActiveMQ if it loses connection to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ActiveMQ "Classic" (i.e. 5.x) then your only option is to use shared storage between the master and the slave. This could be a shared file system or a relational database. This, of course, is a single point of failure.

However, there are both file system and database technologies that can mitigate this risk. For example you could use a replicated file system (e.g. [Ceph](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/cephfs/index.html) or [GlusterFS](https://www.gluster.org)) or a replicated database (e.g. [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html)).

You might also consider using [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) (i.e. the next-generation broker from ActiveMQ) which supports [replication](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#data-replication) natively.